# How to generate a custom Word-based report with different client data? (No Mail Merge)

Tags: excel, ms-word, report

**What I want to do:** Generate a report in Word based on unique data that I manually enter for different clients.

- I collect at least 100 variables of data for different clients.  I must write a report for each client that contains this information.

**What I have tried in the past:** I tried to streamline this process by using Excel to enter the data in select cells and run the Mail Merge function, which would then export the unique data into a templated Word document.

**Problem:** Unfortunately, this process is prone to error and has a tendency to crash my computer.

**Question:** Is there a way that I can successfully make this a seamless process?

- **Note:**  I do NOT have any programming knowledge whatsoever but I am here because I think a non-programming approach is simply not efficient.  I am hoping I can reach a solution to this issue by teaching myself basic programming principles.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - one way is to first add the Microsoft Office Word references in the VBA window. Then you can set up a word document with bookmarks. Then for each data you would like to insert:

```
Doc.Bookmarks("Bookmarknamehere").Select
App.Selection.TypeText "ClientDataHere"
```

You will have to define the word application and document variables and the above will work.